# Automatically Catch Exceptions for PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Evening,

I am currently handling PDO exceptions like this:

```
try{
$db = Db::connect();
$query = $db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table;" );
$query->execute();
}
catch( PDOException $e ) { error( 'MySQL error: ' . $e->getMessage(), __FILE__, __LINE__ ); }
```

My handling each time is exactly the same. So I am wondering if there is a way I can set up that when there is a PDO exception that it automatically runs:

```
catch( PDOException $e ) { error( 'MySQL error: ' . $e->getMessage(), __FILE__, __LINE__ ); }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [Documentation of PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

You can change the error handling to **PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT** or **PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING**

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
```

Or use [set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) and define a handler for all your exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, that should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try and edit the class itself to catch it.