# Is there any way to make PDO exceptions be caught by default?

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo, fatal-error

I use PDO over my webapp. I use this simple code to ensure that the query is executed successfully & handle the error if it fails

```
$stmt = // MySQL query;

if($stmt->execute()){
   // Do something
} else {
   // Handle the error
   echo 'some error';
}
```

It doesn't work because any PDO uncaught exception e.g (duplicate entry primary key) is a fatal error so the PHP script stop execution. I know TRY/CATCH solve this case but i've tons of queries, It'd take long time to use try/catch on each query.

**My Question**

Is there any way to make PDO exceptions be caught by default to be generalize over my webapp ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for error handling using PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421702/best-practice-for-error-handling-using-pdo)

Comment: The whole point of exceptions is not to blindly catch them and throw them away but to act on them. You don't have to try/catch on each query but you must try/catch at some level in your code. "Generalize over" means "suppress errors, fail silently, and malfunction without telling anyone until it's too late to fix the problem because the damage is already done".

Comment: @tadman Thanks for your comment. Please , Read my answer & leave any notes if exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically Catch Exceptions for PDO in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669017/automatically-catch-exceptions-for-pdo-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I found the best practice to handle PDO uncaught exception without using try/catch after reading this

[What-is-SetAttribute-PDO-ATTR_ERRMODE ?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-SetAttribute-PDO-ATTR_ERRMODE-PDO-ERRMODE_EXCEPTION-in-PHP)

1 -  SET attribute `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE`  ----- > `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`

```
PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING  // issue warning and continue executing the script
```

2 -  Check error log file of your apache to determine the error

**IMP NOTE :**

- Do this practice only if you already handle errors through your code e.g (storing the php file name and line of the error in database).
- You can handle warning by using function [error_reporting()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: This is still really risky. If errors happen you need to handle them. You may need to display an error the user can understand, log it for fixing, or unwind things you've already done. Silently ignoring them is going to cause problems.